# How can you get AnyDice to add a flat value to a roll while calculating the "drop lowest" appropriately?

Tags: anydice

I'm trying to calculate the values for 4d4 drop lowest 1 and add 6.

```
ABILITIES: 6 d [highest 3 of 4d{1..4}+6]
loop P over {1..6} {
 output P @ ABILITIES named "Ability [P]"
}
```

Seems to output the exact same as

```
ABILITIES: 6 d [highest 4 of 4d{1..4}+6]
loop P over {1..6} {
 output P @ ABILITIES named "Ability [P]"
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You may also be interested in my [ability score calculator](https://highdiceroller.github.io/icepool/apps/ability_scores.html?num_dice=4&die_size=4&reroll_dice=0&reroll_times=always&num_keep=3&modifier=6&num_ability_repeat=1&num_abilities=6&min_ability=3&max_ability=18&num_arrays=1&p3=3&p4=4&p5=5&p6=6&p7=7&p8=8&p9=9&p10=10&p11=11&p12=12&p13=13&p14=14&p15=15&p16=16&p17=17&p18=18) which also allows you to select a point-buy cost table, among other features.

Answer (score 10):

Adding a number to the `4d4` breaks the connection of the distribution to the individual dice being rolled. Thus the `highest` function can't drop the lowest value any more, since there's now only one random value taken from the more complicated distribution.

[Here's a quick demonstration of that fact](https://anydice.com/program/2e63a):

```
DISTRIBUTION: 4d4+6
loop P over {1..4} {
 output P @ DISTRIBUTION named "die [P]"
}
```

[image: graph of output from Anydice, showing that all the stats are in the first "die"]

There are a few options for how to work around that problem.

One simple idea is just to move the `+6` outside of the function call (adding parentheses as necessary): `([highest 3 of 4d4]+6)`

Another option would be to bake the `+2` per die into the distribution of the individual die rolls. It doesn't matter that this adds 8, since one of the +2s will be dropped along with its random die. From your `4d{1..4}` is seems like you might have started down this road already: `[highest 3 of 4d{3..6}]`

Comment: Honestly a little surprised that I missed that second option especially considering I've been using it for rerolling low numbers on a lot of calculations.  I really have to remember I can set the die values to whatever I want.